# How can one utilize the indices provided by torch.topk()?

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a pytorch tensor `x` of shape `[N, N_g, 2]`. It can be viewed as `N * N_g` 2d vectors. Specifically, `x[i, j, :]` is the 2d vector of the `j`th group in the `i`th batch.

Now I am trying to get the coordinates of vectors of top 5 length in each group. So I tried the following:

(i) First I used `x_len = (x**2).sum(dim=2).sqrt()` to compute their lengths, resulting in `x_len.shape==[N, N_g]`.

(ii) Then I used `tk = x_len.topk(5)` to get the top 5 lengths in each group.

(iii) The desired output would be a tensor `x_top5` of shape `[N, 5, 2]`. Naturally I thought of using `tk.indices` to index `x` so as to obtain `x_top5`. But I failed as it seems such indexing is not supported.

How can I do this?

---

A minimal example:

```
x = torch.randn(10,10,2) # N=10 is the batchsize, N_g=10 is the group size
x_len = (x**2).sum(dim=2).sqrt()
tk = x_len.topk(5)

x_top5 = x[tk.indices]

print(x_top5.shape)
# torch.Size([10, 5, 10, 2])
```

However, this gives `x_top5` as a tensor of shape `[10, 5, 10, 2]`, instead of `[10, 5, 2]` as desired.

Comment: you didn't set the dim param. `tk = x_len.topk(5, dim=1)` for the top 5 lengths in each group. For the output: `x[:, tk.indices, :]`

Comment: @DimitriK.Sifoua the dim parameter is by default `-1`, which is the same as `dim=1` in this case so it shouldn't make any difference. Also, indexing as you suggested gives `[10, 10, 5, 2]` not `[10, 5, 2]`.

Comment: OK for the dim param. The problem comes from indexing because you use 2D tensor instead of 1D tensor. This will work `torch.cat([*map(lambda i: x[i:i+1, tk. indices[i], :], range(x.shape[0]))])`